# How to chown file to containing folders owner

Tags: linux, bash, centos-6, chown

How would you go to chown a file to the containing folder's owner

lets say I moved a file from

> /home/userA/folder/abc.bin

towards:

> /home/userB/finalfolder/abc.bin

How can I chown abc.bin to userB ?

But by determining the userB from the owner of final folder?
This has to be part of a bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `stat -c '%U:%G' home/userB/finalfolder` returns the owner and group of the `finalfolder`, separated by a colon.  This is just the format that `chown` needs.  Thus, use:

```
chown "$(stat -c '%U:%G' home/userB/finalfolder)" /home/userB/finalfolder/abc.bin
```

This works with GNU `stat` which should be fine because you are on centos.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks a lot. hoped there would be a nice imbricated way like this.